# Matrix and implicit-function-theorem

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Let $A\in Mat(\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2})$ such that $A$ is non-inverse matrix and $tr(A)=0$.

Find conditions such that $A_{1,1}=f(A_{2,1},A_{2,2}),A_{1,2}=f(A_{2,1},A_{2,2})$ and find $\frac{dA_{1,2}}{dA_{2,1}}$.

$A$ is non-inverse matrix thus $|A|=A_{1,1}A_{2,2}-A_{2,1}A_{1,2}=0$.

$tr(A)=A_{1,1}+A_{2,2}=
 0 $

I consider implicit-function-theorem is useful here but I a don't know how to approach the problem.

Appreiciate any help.

Comment: Your $d$ should be a partial derivative since we’re talking about a function of more than one variable. You can write the function explicitly here; you do not need the implicit function theorem. $a_{11}=-a_{22}$ and $a_{12}=a_{11}^2/a_{21}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry fixed